# How do you inspect elements in IE like in Firebug?

Tags: internet-explorer, firebug

I was not able to answer this question in an interview. I told them in IE we can't inspect the element. Please help me out regarding the answer.

Comment: Which interview are you talking about? Note that a quick search in your favorite search engine would already have given you this information.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer also has [developer tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) available by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>. Especially in IE 11 they made a big leap forward. There you click on the mouse cursor icon at the left (the (DOM Explorer"), then click the rectangle icon with the cursor inside the panel toolbar and choose the element inside the page by clicking on it.

[image]

In versions prior to IE 11 the dev tools look different. In there you need to switch to the *HTML* panel and then click the cursor icon to inspect the element. There's a [quick introduction to them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at the Microsoft website.

If you prefer the Firebug UI, there's also [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/lite), a fully JavaScript based web development tool, which works in all major browsers.